# (Flutter) TextFormField Change labelColor on Focus

Tags: flutter, dart, form-fields

I am trying to change my `labelText` color when focused. I can change the text color but not when focused.

I have tried all the hint text colors and label text colors, but nothing helps.

```dart
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 15, 0),
  child: TextFormField(
    cursorColor: Colors.lightGreen,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: 'Phone Number',
      hintText: 'Enter a Phone Number',
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.lightGreen
        )
      ),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide()
      ),
    )
  ),
),
```

Here are images of what is happening:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of the labelText or hintText in general or are you asking to have it be one color when not in focus and another when in focus?

Comment: I am looking to change the color of the labelText once its in focus. If you see from my pictures, the label text is grey when not selected (which i want) and then when i do select it I want it to go Black(it goes to blue)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You'd need to have a way determine its focus state and then create a conditional for its color based off of that. This is where a `focusNode` would be helpful. Construct a new `FocusNode` off the widget creation, use that as the `focusNode` property in the `TextFormField`. Then in color property of the `TextStyle` property of the `TextFormField` you could add something like:

```dart
FocusNode myFocusNode = new FocusNode();

...

  return TextFormField(
    focusNode: myFocusNode,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: 'test',
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
        color: myFocusNode.hasFocus ? Colors.blue : Colors.black
      )
    ),
  );
```

EDIT : Just a quick note, you'll probably need to make sure this is in a `StatefulWidget` and then add a listener to the `focusNode` you created and call `setState` on any events on that `focusNode`. Otherwise you wont see any changes.

Comment: this did not work. I added a focus  node like you said and followed your example. The labelStyle remained the same color weather in focus or not.

Comment: humm.. are you saying call set set on the labelText?

Comment: You don't setState on a property, you call it on an event which that calls a rebuild of the entire widget/class. You're calling setState on the focus event. This would be done by adding a listener in the initState for example. Like : 

myFocusNode.addListener((){
  setState((){});
})

don't forget to dispose of your listeners to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: perfect, that did it. Thank you!

Comment: This is my first time using a listener (sorry im a beginner, where do I dispose of the listener at?

Comment: you override the dispose() method just like you do the initState(). You would need to make the (){} function it's own variable and then call it in both the addListener and removeListener methods of the focusNode you created. This is likely something best read up on in depth rather than my quick explanation.

Comment: I will, I appreciate it!

Comment: Ok, i found an issue.... I have 6 different forms, and when i add the focus node to the forms, they call go into focus. I dont need to do 6 different focusnodes do it?

Comment: yes, each focus node is meant for each field. That's how you determine where you have focus or where to set focus if you wish to move the user's focus programmatically. An option you may want to consider is to make your own class that wraps all of this color-change-on-focus/unfocus functionality into one place. Then use that class as your way to make text fields. This would actually be a bit more efficient since then you'd only call a rebuild of each textfield on focus change events instead of the whole form/page.

Comment: This method is working for changing the color of the text field when focused, but the color does not revert to the original one when blurred. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Use the theme, you only have to do it once for all input fields.
      floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),

Comment: This is a good start, although I think a theme-based solution is more sustainable e.g. keeps your code DRY. e.g. inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
    ),

Comment: if you don't want to use focus nodes you can achieve the same effect by setting the primarySwatch:Colors.blue in ThemeData

Answer (score 41):

Use themes, this would only have to be done once in a central place:

```
inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
),
```

Comment: The OP asked to change labelText color when focused. This code does not change  labelText color when focused

Comment: It was so simple all along and I was wasting my time on StatefulWidget?

Comment: @mister_cool_beans no the OP asked exactly this.

Comment: It is the best solution.

Answer (score 27):

## The Summary

You might want to check out [Flutter Cookbook's Focus and text fields](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus) recipe.

Essentially, we have to:

1. Create a `FocusNode` property.
2. Add initialization and disposal to it.
3. Add it to the `TextFormField`.
4. Add a focus request on every tap on the `TextFormField`.

### 1. Create a `FocusNode` property

```dart
class CustomTextFormFieldState extends State<CustomTextFormField> {
  FocusNode _focusNode;
  ...
```

### 2. Add initialization and disposal to it

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _focusNode = FocusNode();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _focusNode.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

### 3. Add it to the `TextFormField`

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return TextFormField(
    focusNode: _focusNode,
    ...
```

### 4. Add a focus request on every tap on the `TextFormField`

**Don't forget to use `setState`**:

```dart
void _requestFocus(){
  setState(() {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
  });
}
```

Add the method to the `TextFormField`'s `onTap` property:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return TextFormField(
    focusNode: _focusNode,
    onTap: _requestFocus,
    ...
```

Answer (score 24):

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/labelStyle.html

```
labelStyle: MaterialStateTextStyle.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
          final Color color = states.contains(MaterialState.focused)
              ? Colors.pink
              : Colors.orange;
          return TextStyle(color: color);
        }),
```

Comment: That's the right, and definitely the most correct answer.

Comment: This shouldn't be so low.

Comment: The only real answer.

Comment: Focused label stays the default grey - this is for the TextField with the OutlineInputBorder.

Comment: This answer worked best for me, and doesn't need a setState which is great. You can obviously add other options to the TextStyle eg: FontWeight etc

Answer (score 12):

A quick solution is changing the `primarySwatch` from the `theme` of the Widget `MaterialApp`. The only disadvantage is that a `Material Color` is required.

[image: on focus textfield image]

[image]

Answer (score 12):

for active/click

```
floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow),
```

for inactive

```
labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
```

below is complete example

```
TextField(
         decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Verify Password',
            focusColor: appColor,
            labelText: "Verify Password",
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: appColor),
            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always
         ),
         cursorColor: appColor,
)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is the cleanest solution and how it's supposed to be implemented.

Answer (score 10):

I solve this problem with a Focus widget. First I defined a Color-Variable for each Field:

```
final _lowColor = Colors.amber[50];   // use your own colors
final _highColor = Colors.amber[200];

Color _field1Color = _lowColor;
Color _field2Color = _lowColor;
...
```

Then I wrapped each TextFormField with a Focus Widget and change the fieldColor:

```
child: Focus(
  onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
    setState(() => _field1Color = hasFocus ? _highColor : _lowColor);
  },
  child: TextFormField(
    ...
      color: _field1Color,
    ...
    ),
  ), 
),
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly for me!

Answer (score 8):

Here is a quick method without using stateful widget

```
 return Theme( // 1) wrap with theme widget
   data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(primaryColor: //2) color you want here)
   child: TextFormField(
     focusNode: myFocusNode,
     decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'test',      
    ),
   ),
  );
```

Comment: The Text of the unfocused label is "hintColor: ". But it doesn't work, if you use a TextStyle color property in the hintText property of the InputDecoration. I can't tell why not...

Comment: This is hands down the easier way to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming that this needs to apply through the application. Would it be better to do the above or do it at a theme level?

Answer (score 5):

One more clean way to do it with styles (you can add styles to the main theme and use for dark \ light modes)

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "some label",
    labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
    floatingLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),
  ),),
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### Update

As mentioned by [Guilherme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5501064/guilherme-v) in the comment, the later version of Flutter uses different logic to get the color

```dart
Color _getActiveColor(ThemeData themeData) {
  if (isFocused) {
    return themeData.colorScheme.primary;
  }
  return themeData.hintColor;
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/b22742018b3edf16c6cadd7b76d9db5e7f9064b5/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart#L2030)

You will now need to set it from the `colorScheme` instead

```dart
ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
    primary: activeColor,
  ),
)
```

---

#### Original answer

After digging the source code for the `InputDecorator` used to determine the label color, here's what I found.

```dart
TextStyle _getFloatingLabelStyle(ThemeData themeData) {
  final Color color = decoration.errorText != null
    ? decoration.errorStyle?.color ?? themeData.errorColor
    : _getActiveColor(themeData);
  final TextStyle style = themeData.textTheme.subtitle1.merge(widget.baseStyle);
  return style
    .copyWith(color: decoration.enabled ? color : themeData.disabledColor)
    .merge(decoration.labelStyle);
}

Color _getActiveColor(ThemeData themeData) {
  if (isFocused) {
    switch (themeData.brightness) {
      case Brightness.dark:
        return themeData.accentColor;
      case Brightness.light:
        return themeData.primaryColor;
    }
  }
  return themeData.hintColor;
}
```

In short, to change the label color, set the `primaryColor` light theme or `accentColor` for dark theme.

Another tip: To change the label color while it's not focused, set `hintColor`.

```dart
ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
  primaryColor: Colors.red,
  accentColor: Colors.white,
  hintColor: Colors.pink,
)
```

Comment: It seems things have changed in the latest flutter version. Now instead of using "primaryColor" and "accentColor" we need to change "colorScheme": 

``ThemeData.dark().copyWith(colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(primary: activeColor),"``

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/b22742018b3edf16c6cadd7b76d9db5e7f9064b5/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart#L2030

Comment: Thanks! Updated the answer to reflect this

Comment: thanks ,after long time ,this is good answer

Answer (score 1):

you can also use labelStyle when the text field is in focus and if the text field is erroneous (caused by not following the validation)

```
labelText: 'Password',
     labelStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black54,
          ),
//when error has occured
     errorStyle: TextStyle(
       color: Colors.black,
         ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using a `StatefulWidget` and `Focus` widget.
I use StatefulWidget because you need to use setState to notify the color change when focus on input

[image]

```
class InputEmail extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputEmailState createState() => _InputEmailState();
}

class _InputEmailState extends State<InputEmail> {
  Color _colorText = Colors.black54;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const _defaultColor = Colors.black54;
    const _focusColor = Colors.purple;

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
      child: Focus(
        onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
          // When you focus on input email, you need to notify the color change into the widget.
          setState(() => _colorText = hasFocus ? _focusColor : _defaultColor);
        },
        child: TextField(
          // Validate input Email
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'example@domain.com',
            labelText: 'Email',
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: _colorText),
            
            // Default Color underline
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black26),
            ),

            // Focus Color underline
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple),
            ),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.mail,
              color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote

There is a `floatingLabelStyle` parameter in the `inputDecoration` instead of `labelStyle`. I used `floatingLabelStyle` it worked for me.

InputDecorator(
decoration: InputDecoration(
labelText: 'lablelText',
floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink),
enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
borderSide: BorderSide(
color: Colors.grey
),
),
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
),
child: Text('Text'),
),

Answer (score 0):

If You want to change the primary color. Just simply define add the `primaryColor` of the Widget MaterialApp

```
const appPrimaryColor = Color(0xFF746DF7);
```

```
ThemeData theme() {
  return ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
    fontFamily: "Inter",
    appBarTheme: appBarTheme(),
    textTheme: textTheme(),
    inputDecorationTheme: inputDecorationTheme(),
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
    primaryColor: appPrimaryColor // <------ HERE
  );
}
```

```
MaterialApp(
   title: 'Flutter Demo',
   theme: theme(), // <------ HERE
   home: SplashScreen(),
   routes: routes,
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Material 3 way using *ColorScheme* for text color and *InputDecorationTheme* for border color:

```
var focusColor = Colors.blue;
var nonFocusColor = Colors.grey;

MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
      primary: focusColor,
      onSurfaceVariant: nonFocusColor,
      // other required props ...
    ),
    inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: focusColor),
      ),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: nonFocusColor),
      ),
    ),
    useMaterial3: true,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the textfield with `Theme` and set the primary color to whatever you want the label color to be

Comment: Simple and working. Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

There is a 'lableStyle' in 'decoration', just like:

```
labelText: 'Description',
labelStyle: TextStyle(
  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
)),
```

Comment: It's the primary setting. This also affects when textFormField is not on focus

Answer (score -1):

There is a floatingLabelStyle parameter in the InputDecoration, you can use it like this:

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "label",
    hintText: "hint",
    labelStyle: GoogleFonts.roboto(
      color: color.labelColor,
    ),
    floatingLabelStyle: GoogleFonts.roboto(
      color: color.defaultGreen,
    ),),
```