# TextFormField label style changes when widget is selected

Tags: flutter, label, styles

I want to make use of a TextFormField in my flutter app.

The text input field is show with the label. The hint text is not visible. When I select the widget, the hint text is shown and at the same time the label style changes. The text shrinks and become blue.

I tried this by just adding the code in the default flutter app, so it easy to reproduce

TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Demo Label", 
    hintText: "Foo"
)

Where can I change this behaviour?  I would like to have a consistent label, no matter if the widget is selected or not.

Comment: Similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411599/flutter-textformfield-change-labelcolor-on-focus

Comment: The other question is to modify the label when it has focus. I want to have a label which is consistent no matter if the widget has focus or not. Also when text is entered or not, the label is the same.

I woud be nice if I can control everything via the app theme.

Comment: Any solution found for this?

Answer (score 0):

Add your own Text widget for the label text, do not use "labelText" property in decoration property of TextFormField.

```
Text("Email", style: TextStyle()), <-- use custom Text widget
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    //labelText: "Email",      <-- do not use this
    //labelStyle: TextStyle(), <-- do not use this
    hintText: "Please enter your email",
    hintStyle: TextStyle(),
  )
)
```